# How to do proper nesting in a Magento theme?

Tags: templates, magento, nested

I've copied the default Magento theme in the two dirs and renamed it.
After a lot of tweaking I've come to a point where I'm stuck.

I've got a 3columns.phtml file where the basic layout resides:

- top (top.phtml)
- header (header.phtml)
- main (main.phtml)
- footer (footer.phtml)

with main.phtml:

- left.phtml
- middle.phtml
- right.phtml

Now when I referenced these blocks separately in the 3columns.phtml with the getChildHtml() function everything was peachy. Now, after putting them in the main.phtml file it doesn't seem to work anymore. Any content in the main.phtml is not shown (not even simpel html tags). Thinking it could have to do with the xml layout files I looked into page.xml but found out some things are handled by catalog.xml

I now have these block declarations in page.xml:

- top (no template= set)
- header (no template= set)
- main (template="page/html/main.phtml")

  - left (template="page/html/left.phtml")
  - middle (template="page/html/middle.phtml")
  - topmenu (template="page/html/topmenu.phtml")
  - breadcrumbs (no template= set)
  - right (template="page/html/right.phtml")
- footer (template="page/html/footer.phtml")

And eventhough top and header have no template set their html shows up fine in the frontend. the footer shows up fine too.
Left's output is shown, but not wrapped by main's output.
Right's output the same.
Middle's output shows, but any getChildHtml calls in it don't.

Any ideas as to what's going on?
Also, how do the page.xml and catalog.xml relate to the template? Does every single call to getChildHtml have to be in the page.xml file? what's the difference between page and catalog.

The  part of page.xml: http://www.snipplr.com/view/66919/part-of-pagexml-not-working/

The  part of catalog.xml: http://www.snipplr.com/view/66920/default-part-of-catalogxml-not-working/

The 3columns.phtml: http://www.snipplr.com/view/66921/main-theme-file-3columnsphtml/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the detail explanation you can read Alanstorm's book, "No Frills Magento Layout".
I'll give you "brief" explanation so that you have a little enlightment.

In our controller, when we call `$this->loadLayout();`, it will automatically "call" `<default>` handle.

Later, all of the handle in all layout xml will be merged.

Let's say you have `<default>` in page.xml, then you also have `<default>` in your catalog.xml.
After the call of `$this->loadLayout()` those `<default>` from page.xml and catalog.xml will be merged.

That's the relation between them.

We can say `<default>` is the main of everything. It is the main structure. Any other layout usually "referencing" from it.

Let's say you want to add something in the main body (content), we will call:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="testing" template="some/test/template.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

Those tag means: Put `<block type="core/template" name="testing" template="some/test/template.phtml"></block>` under block with name content.

If you see the definition of block with name content:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
    <label>Main Content Area</label>
</block>
```

You can see the type is `core/text_list`. Block with this type will render every child under it and it DOES NOT need a template.
As you can see, there is no definition for template="blabla/blibli.phtml".

The type of block that have template is `core/block_template`. In this type of block, if you want to render its child, you have to "consciously" call `echo $this->getChildHtml('mykid')`.

Do you get it?

That's why your definition is incorrect: `<block type="core/text_list" name="main" as="main" translate="label" template="page/html/main.phtml">`.

`core/text_list` doesn't need and doesn't have a template. You can imagine if "content" is a `core/block_template`: every time you're going to create a child under "content" you have to "consciously" call `echo $this->getChildHtml('mykid')`. Let's say you have 100 child, you will need to call `echo $this->getChildHtml('mykid1')`, `echo $this->getChildHtml('mykid2')`, ..., `echo $this->getChildHtml('mykid100')`.

Then let's see your catalog.xml:

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <block type="core/template" name="top" template="page/html/top.phtml"></block>

    <block type="core/template" name="header" template="page/html/header.phtml"></block>

    <block type="core/template" name="main" template="page/html/main.phtml">
        <block type="core/template" name="left" template="page/html/left.phtml"></block>
        <block type="core/template" name="middle" template="page/html/middle.phtml"></block>
        <block type="core/template" name="right" template="page/html/right.phtml"></block>
    </block>

    <reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map">
            <label>Site Map</label>
            <url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" />
            <title>Site Map</title>
        </action>
    </reference>

    <block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
</default>
```

I don't get it what you're going to achieve from this catalog.xml. There are no reference for: `<block type="core/template" name="top" template="page/html/top.phtml"></block>`, `<block type="core/template" name="header" template="page/html/header.phtml"></block>`, etc.

If you're going to add some layout (children), you need to "referencing" from an existing one. Let's say you're going to add children under block with name "main" and you're going to put the code in your catalog.xml:

Then your catalog.xml will be like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="main">
        <block type="core/template" name="i" template="my/new/template1.phtml"></block>
        <block type="core/template" name="dont" template="my/new/template2.phtml"></block>
        <block type="core/template" name="know" template="my/new/template3.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Now it depends on the definition of block with name "main".

If your block with name "main" is:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="main" as="main" translate="label">
...
</block>
```

then those blocks (blocks with name "i", "dont", "know") will be automatically called (rendered).

If your block with name "main" is:

```
<block type="core/template" name="main" as="main" translate="label" template="page/html/main.phtml">
...
</block>
```

Then you need to call this in your `page/html/main.phtml`:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('i');
echo $this->getChildHtml('dont');
echo $this->getChildHtml('know');
```

That's as far as I can explain as it's pretty much incorrect things in your layout, if you get the point, you can fix it by reading my explanation.

Few tips:

- To see which handles loaded, put this code in your controller under `$this->loadLayout();` :

  ```
  $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
  $updates = $layout->getUpdate();
  $handles = $updates->getHandles();
  var_dump($handles);
  ```
- To see the generated xml from load layout, put this code in your controller under `$this->loadLayout();` :

  ```
  $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
  $updates = $layout->getUpdate();
  $xml = $updates->asString();
  var_dump($xml);
  ```

Maybe you will need `echo "<pre>" / wrap using htmlentities / Mage::log` for neat looking purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible explanations.

Since left, middle, and right are children of 'main' you need to call getChildChildHtml (note the double child).

Since 'main' is a child (nested) inside 3columns it is not considered it's own page type (i.e. 1 column), the better solution seems to edit the 3columns.phtml file to have the blocks that you want.

When calling getChildHtml the parameter passed to it is the name='' attribute in the xml (so for example if the 'right' block needs to be called, then we need to find the name attribute in the xml - in this case it's 'right' and use that for the parameter).

The left, footer etc. blocks are showing because they are already being called in the 3columns.phtml file.

Also double check that the template file to 'main' is in the right location.

I hope these were some helpful pointers